# How to find the first and last point of the clamped spline?

Tags: cubics, bezier-curve, spline

I want to draw a clamped spline. How to calculate the first and last value?. 
I got the algorithm from below link http://www.physics.arizona.edu/~restrepo/475A/Notes/sourcea-/node35.html

They did the below calculation to find the first and last point.
Step 2 Set  $\alpha_0=3(a_1-a_0)/h_0-3$ FPO 
$\alpha_n= 3$ FPN  $-3(a_n-a_{n-1})/h_{n-1}$

and also looked this blog.http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/01/01/javascript-cubic-splines/ They used the same logic, but i can't understand how to calculate the first and last point.

Anyone please suggest me..

Thanks,
Santhiya